# Как перенести wordpress с https на http сервер?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, https

Есть интернет-магазин на `wordpress` c 20 тыс товарами на сервере с *ssl*. 
За счет картинок товаров занимает много места.

Мне нужно протестировать новые функции и для этого я скопировал его структуру и базу данных (без картинок товаров) на тестовый сервер, но уже без *ssl* в папку **model**

Столкнулся с тем, что стили/скрипты/картинки все равно пытаются подгрузиться через **https** несмотря на то, что в `wp_options` сделаны замены полей
*siteurl* и *home*, кеш плагины удалены, а в `functions.php` обращение идет через

```
<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>
```

Т.е. по сути подгружается только html каркас с ошибками загрузки стилей/скриптов/картинкок в консоли. Плюс не удается получить доступ к wp_admin, получаю ошибку

> ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

файл *.htaccess*

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /model/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /model/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: .htaccess тут не причем, прочитайте внимательно как правильно перенести сайт wordpress, ваша проблема в том, что вы заменяете домен в БД только `siteurl и home` опций, а нужно польностю по БД, ниболее быстрый и простой способ без ломания частей сайта испольпользывать wp-cli, а именно команду wp search-replace "старый домен" "новый"

Comment: Вася, ну как же так. Вы тут уже давно. Сто раз цитировалось: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/767562/220220

Comment: @KAGG Design не приходилось натыкаться и сталкиваться с подобной проблемой прежде. Пробовал перенести базу с помощью замены путей через плагин https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/ - результат аналогичный. Пробую перенести с помощью плагина `duplicator` c пропуском папки uploads (перед процеесом все горит зеленым, только серое уведомление напротив базы данных)  - получаю ошибку ` Why is the package build stuck at 5%?` и бекап 0 байт

Comment: @Nik Horse спасибо, но описал выше почему дело не в бд, пробовал вводить замены и с помощью `Скрипта Database Search and Replace` - все тоже самое

Comment: @Вася у duplicator есть пошаговая инструкция, как бороться с этой ошибкой. Она возникает на некоторых (неправильно настроенных) хостингах.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)